# Share objects between subsystems

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, architecture

What is the best approach in terms of maintainability, extensibility and performance to share Data Objects between many subsystems?

I mean this, I have this system with these layers:

```
controller <-> Service (bl) <-> Domain <-> Database
```

We can have N `controller`, from web or a web-service that has access to the `Service` layer, so at this point we have an API that N Subsystems will consume.

I'm using an `ORM` with the needed entity and we are handling these entities everywhere inside Service and Domain layers.

My question is, what is the best approach to share this data object (information) to the subsystems from my service Layer?

Map? XML

Comment: could you clarify on what you mean by "share". You mean sending them, serializing them, caching shared instances ...

Comment: I mean, send to and from services or controller... Maybe a service will have this method postToStackOverFlow(User user, Question question). User and Question are the same object used as entities. I don't like the idea of using these same objects in the presentation layer. What should I use instead?

Comment: Why do you feel you shouldn't use them in the presentation layer?  Presumably they're just beans, right?  In some cases where my domain objects don't match what I need for my presentation layer (form data, for example) I might create a bean for that purpose.

Comment: Because we are modularizing the project into many others and we don't want that project dependency from one to other and from other to one.

Comment: also, the service layer can be consumed from remote projects

Comment: If you are using SOAP-based web-service as your "Service" then there is absolutely nothing wrong with sharing them to the controllers. Your web service will have unified interface - WSDL. This interface will describe all necessary information about data objects to controllers.

Comment: But, if you have lots of controllers and lots of data objects consider buinding SOA with Enterprise Service Bus as it's core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no doubt, at this time (2013) the best approach is to use `json` objects to share through restful webservices that can be consumed from the web app front end and from external clients consuming the API.